# Naming convention for asynchronous operations

Tags: web-services, naming-conventions

I have a web service that triggers some long operations on the server via asynchronous methods. Each operation has 3 methods:

- One of them start the operation and immediately returns a ticket number.
- One of them is called continuously from the client; it receives the ticket number and returns a boolean value, saying whether the operation is done.
- The last one of them is called only after the operation is finished; it receives the ticket number and returns the result of the operation.

I'm not sure how to call this methods. I think about calling the methods something like this:

- OperationName_Start
- OperationName_IsReady
- OperationName_GetResult

but I'm afraid I could be reinventing the wheel. Is there any well known naming convention for this usage pattern?

Comment: So what did you go with @Doug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a shame you couldn't get an answer the first time around. I would strongly suggest reading this [SOA Principles Link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soa-design/) to gain a better understanding of the principals and importance of web service naming.

It's key to remember to **name from the perspective of the consumer** and **maximise consumability and re-useability**. Its also useful to remember that when you invoke a service, your are performing and action on an object i.e. you should have a **verb** and a **noun**. Also remember that web services are very very similar to functions in an object oriented language, so its helpful to think of what the code of the function of the web service would look like.

It's helpful to consider scenarios like:

- What would happen if i changed the system the web service was calling?
- Is there another scenario that could call this service?
- How granular should the service be? What are the performance impacts of these decisions?

Without knowing the business context of what you are trying to achieve, we'll assume a basic example of submitting and electronic payment.

In this scenario, you may have:

- **ElectronicPayment_SendPayment** (Note: the use of 'Send' keeping the business context, not the technical context; send could be via email, post, webservice. From your 'Start' example, what are you starting; here, the intent of the service is apparent)
- **ElectronicPayment_CheckStatus** (Note: this is from the consumer's perspective. It's likely that  checking processing status is a generic service, that could be seperated into something along the lines of `CheckProcessingStatus (TicketNumber tN)`
- **ElectronicPayment_RetrieveReciept** (Note: Request/Response pattern with semantic link. Business Context of receipt and payment maintained)

Naming is highly contextual, and the above is not perfect, but hopefully it helps yourself and others who stumble upon this.

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of answers, I assume that apparently there isn't a widely used standard on this issue, so it's OK to roll my own.

I chose to stick with:

- OperationName_Start
- OperationName_IsReady
- OperationName_GetResult